# Cross site attack warning each time I open Firefox

Tags: security, xss, noscript, penetration-testing, client-side-attacks

Each time I open Firefox, I get this error. I have NoScript installed. There also isn't any tabs open that has anything to do with this website.
I tried clearing my cache and local content, but it still keeps coming.

> NoScript detected a potential Cross-Site Scripting attack  from [...]
>   to https://smartfonts.com.  Suspicious data:  (URL)
>   https://smartfonts.com/{{metaImage}}

Comment: This question is better suited for [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Can you please share more details, may be snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, after visiting a wikipedia page. To get rid of it click the plus sign to open a new tab. Firefox will then show some recent visited page previews, use the elipsis (3 dots) menu to remove the relevant entry from the firefox history.

Comment: This can be marked as the answer. It worked for me. Because I don't normally show the recently visited pages (or in my case of Firefox version 60.6.1 it's called the Top Sites), first I needed to go to the Firefox settings page and put a check mark in the "Top Sites" checkbox for the new tab preferences. Then I could delete the bad link.